# Get String for another class

Tags: android

i want send string from here :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder hold, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
    final String id=list_data.get(position).get("id"); //This is my string
}
```

to here :

```
private void hapus(){
    class cari extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        ....

        KEY_ID = ??? //here

        ....
    }

}
```

Full code :

[AdapterList.java](http://bls.hol.es/AdapteList)

[galery.java](http://bls.hol.es/galery)

im so sorry can't paste full code here, because i've pasted the same code here

Comment: you can use interface

Comment: im new in android. But I will try to find what is the interface in google. tanks for your comment

Comment: check my ans...

Comment: Is your method in same class as of onBindViewHolder or a different class or activity??

Comment: @Iqbal check  my update ans it will sure help you

Comment: @sumit My methods in different classes and the same activity

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod OK.. i wil try this

Comment: I have done what you suggest and I am very grateful. But there is no solution that helps. I have added the full code in the question. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Have onBindViewHolder return the string ID.

Comment: what do you mean like this? 
return Strig id;

Comment: I'm going to need more context.

Comment: Context context;

Comment: *facepalm*. Yes, you can have the method return the string. Another solution, store the ID in a public variable in the class. Just do this "return id;"

Comment: I have done what you suggest and I am very grateful. But there is no solution that helps. I have added the full code in the question. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

try this make your String public static so your can use it anywhere in your application

crete one class like this

```
public class Utils{
public static String final_id="";
}
```

now access your String like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder hold, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
    Utils.final_id=list_data.get(position).get("id"); //This is my string
}
```

you can use it retrive your String data like this

```
private void hapus(){
class cari extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
String KEY_ID = Utils.final_id;
}

}
```

Comment: i have an Error:(110, 16) error: <identifier> expected

Comment: This is my error code Error:(31, 30) error: Illegal static declaration in inner class AdapterList.Utils
modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

Comment: ohk declare your utils class outside your adapter class

Comment: I have done what you suggest and I am very grateful. But there is no solution that helps. I have added the full code in the question. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Calling an Asynchronous Task from onBindViewHolder() method of ViewHolder class is not an acceptable approach, because for every item its recycles in the Recycler ListView, the Asyn Task gets called again and again. (even during scrolling.)

Change the logic (or) use different way to handle the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use Nilesh's answer or you can use a constructor to initialize your String.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder hold, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
    final String id=list_data.get(position).get("id"); //This is my string
    new yourClass(id);
}
```

Then inside your class

```
private String id;

public yourClass(){} //default constructor

public yourClass(String id){
//Now you can use this id wherever you want to use
this.id = id;
}
```

Using constructor you can send multiple things if you want and initialize them in your class and use them according to your requirement.
Hope it helps!!